# Select sum with condition postgres sql + rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I would like to sum the score column of the table 'recordings' group by user id and later I would like to compare the sum of score of each user. for this I wrote the below query

**To sum the score by user**

> Recording.select("sum(score) as score,
>   user_id").group(:user_id).order("score DESC")
>
> SELECT sum(score) as score, user_id FROM "recordings" GROUP BY user_id

**To compare the sum of score**

> Recording.select("sum(score) as score,
>   user_id").group(:user_id).where("score > 200")
>
> SELECT sum(score) as score, user_id FROM "recordings" WHERE (score >
>   200 ) GROUP BY user_id

The second query doesn't return the valid records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not comment on the role of `score > 200`, but I suspect, this is what you actually want:

```
SELECT sum(score) AS sum_score, user_id
FROM   recordings
GROUP  BY user_id
HAVING sum(score) > 200
```

Meaning, you want those users where the total score (the sum of all scores) exceeds 200.
Your query would build a sum of individual scores that exceed 200. Possible, but unlikely?

You laid the groundworks for your problem by using the column name as alias for the result of the aggregate function:

```
sum(score) as score
```

That's a loaded footgun. I used `sum_score` instead to disambiguate.

You promptly shot yourself in the foot with that by confusing the alias with the base column. You cannot refer to column aliases in the `WHERE` or `HAVING` clause, where you can only reference the base tables. In addition you confused the role of `WHERE` and `HAVING`. [The manual has the basics about that.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-HAVING).